# Why is html2canvas causing incorrect display on Firefox for LaTeX output but works fine on Edge and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas, mathjax

I am building a site that allows LaTeX input for .png output. Currently, it works to provide a perfect .png picture of a LaTeX equation on Edge/Chrome but I am unable to replicate using the same code on Firefox.

Here is the output on Chromium browsers:
[image: equation on Chromium browswers]

[image: equation on Firefox browswers]

No errors exist on the Chromium platforms, but errors exist on Firefox:

```
#1 0ms Starting document clone with size 1920x955 scrolled to 0,0 html2canvas.min.js:20:191994
#1 162ms Unable to access cssRules property DOMException: CSSStyleSheet.cssRules getter: Not allowed to access cross-origin stylesheet
    createStyleClone https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    createElementClone https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    cloneNode https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    appendChildNode https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    cloneChildNodes https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    cloneNode https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    appendChildNode https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    cloneChildNodes https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    cloneNode https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    fn https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    Js https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    e https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    e https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    a https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    a https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    Js https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    <anonymous> https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/html2canvas.min.js:20
    convertToImage https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/symbolsLatex.js:82
    renderEquation https://www.pangram-world.com/scripts/symbolsLatex.js:37
html2canvas.min.js:20:192835
#1 393ms Document cloned, element located at -9999,675.2999877929688 with size 169.43333435058594x35.01666259765625 using computed rendering html2canvas.min.js:20:191994
#1 393ms Starting DOM parsing html2canvas.min.js:20:191994
#1 428ms Starting renderer for element at -9999,675.2999877929688 with size 170x36 html2canvas.min.js:20:191994
#1 430ms Canvas renderer initialized (170x36) with scale 1 html2canvas.min.js:20:191994
#1 449ms Finished rendering html2canvas.min.js:20:191994
Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://www.pangram-world.com/style/bootstrap.css
Source Map URL: bootstrap.css.map
```

Note: I downloaded html2canvas and Bootstrap and it is working as expected on Chromium and Bootstrap is working as expected on Firefox. But the outputs of the LaTeX are not the same.

This is the codeblock that prints the image for html2canvas:

```
function convertToImage() {
    const mathContainer = document.getElementById('mathContainer');
    // Temporarily position the mathContainer off-screen
    mathContainer.style.position = 'absolute';
    mathContainer.style.left = '-9999px';
    mathContainer.style.visibility = 'visible';

    // Render the image with html2canvas
    html2canvas(mathContainer, {
        backgroundColor: background === 'transparent' ? 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' : 'white',
    }).then(canvas => {
        // Now that the image is rendered, reset the mathContainer's style
        mathContainer.style.position = '';
        mathContainer.style.left = '';
        mathContainer.style.visibility = 'hidden';

        // Set the source of the result image and display it
        const resultImage = document.getElementById('resultImage');
        resultImage.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        resultImage.style.display = 'block'; // Show the image
        resultImage.style.margin = 'auto'; // Center the image if needed

        // Create the download link
        createDownloadLink(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));

        // Create and display the copy button
        createCopyButton(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    });
}
```

The initial position is to stop a double-up on rendering. I can't seem to work out what the error is suggesting is wrong or why it is wrong on Firefox and what are my workarounds.

I had considered just stopping html2canvas for any Firefox browsers, but that seems drastic. I would prefer to fix the image output for all browsers.

The HTML head is:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/cards.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/symbols.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- ... favicon ... -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="images/android-chrome-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="512x512" href="images/android-chrome-512x512.png">

    <script src="scripts/main.js" defer></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/18fe617275.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you please provide how you do imports in the html file. (the <head> tag content in order)

Comment: @MustafaReda - good call. I hadn't thought of this. But is there anything wrong with the way it is set up there?

Comment: may this help? https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2197

Comment: I added a question there, but @MustafaReda, other than extensions interfering, there seemed to be no resolve there.